# Method 'Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent.LaunchUrl' not found

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Trying to use  `Microsoft.Identity.Client v1.1.0-preview` to authenticate users via Microsoft.  When I execute `App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync`, even with a try/catch around it, it terminates the app.

The android device log shows

```
Info 6756 MonoDroid System.MissingMethodException: 
  Method 'Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent.LaunchUrl' not found.
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnResume (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in <e975227ac8644a30bb0866117325de0d>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:40d0e467-e2e5-447f-a0b5-87cb60ce49a7 (intptr,intptr)
```

If you try to just build in Release mode, it won't.  It has a similar error in the output window.

```
Mono.Linker.MarkException: 
Error processing method: 'System.Void Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationActivity::OnResume()' in assembly:
 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: 
  Failed to resolve System.Void
  Android.Support.CustomTabs.CustomTabsIntent::LaunchUrl(Android.App.Activity,Android.Net.Uri)
```

Does anyone know if they have just abandoned this code, or better yet, any idea how to make it work?  It use to work for iOS, but now even that has some issues after the login process is complete.

Comment: Did you add the `microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity` to the manifest? That could cause app termination

Comment: Does the device you're trying to run this on have a web browser that supports Chrome or Chrome custom tabs? It may be trying to pop the browser and failing because the device/emulator doesn't have a support browser installed

Comment: I do have an activity defined that is  microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity in the manifest.  I have attempted this on a physical Galaxy s4 that has Chrome installed, and an android emulator, which the emulator does not have Chrome, but it does have the default functioning Browser. Both fail the same way, referencing the missing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had a bad experience with `Microsoft.Identity.Client` on Android, please pay attention to the next things:

- Use the latest nightly build instead of preview version
- Ensure you meet all the requirements: Android Lollipop+ & Google Chrome is installed
- Follow the [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/) carefully
- Follow the [github project page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet), I found most of the solutions there

It seems like there is a problem [with a custom URL scheme](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/#Android) in the manifest, so I would recheck it first.

Comment: Since the preview is supposed to be "supported", and since it works with iOS, I would rather not go back to an alpha.  Based on the way the iOS version works, I don't seem even far enough along in the process for the URL scheme to be the issue.  I will try to get Chrome installed in my Emulator.

Comment: I corrected myself - "nightly build" instead of "alpha". So you will actually not go back but forward. Otherwise you will be forced to use older version of Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: That makes more sense, but, where do I find the nightly build?  I'm using NuGet to get the preview and it doesn't show that.

Comment: Check https://www.myget.org/feed/aad-clients-nightly/package/nuget/Microsoft.Identity.Client

Comment: Perfect.  I was able to load that.  Now the emulator blows but says it is because Chrome is not installed, which is expected.  But, my physical device with chrome doesn't throw an exception.  It just never returns from App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync after I login.

Comment: After a few more tweaks, it seems to work. Big thanks.  Although it is driven through the OnActivityResult method in the MainActifvity, and so is Googles.  For Googles, I can specify a specific requestCode so I can identify it. This only seems to have 0 for that.  Being able to identify it would be helpful.  Any idea when this will move on from Alpha?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Glad to help, you can accept my answer.